# Bug: Can not start NetBeans 7.3 with JDK 8

Tags: java, netbeans

I have `NetBeans 7.3` and I upgraded my JDK to `1.8`. Now I tried to open NetBeans and was getting `Loading Cached Objects` message on its loading window and then NetBeans got terminated.

I was getting following exception (available in \var\log\messages.log file):

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener can not access a member of class org.openide.filesystems.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"`

What is the probable reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its a bug in NetBeans 7.3 and the details of this can be found *[here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229191)*.

JDK 8 works with [Netbeans 8+](https://netbeans.org/downloads/).

If you wish to continue using Netbeans 7.x with older version of Java revert JDK location in netbeans using following steps:

- Go to NetBeans installation inside you will find `/etc` folder
- Open `netbeans.conf` file of etc folder
- Change the path to earlier jdk version which is specified against `netbeans_jdkhome` property. Now open your NetBeans it will work.

Comment: And you can find & download the earlier versions of JDK at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html