# Netbeans does not opens when jre 1.8 has installed

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, netbeans-7.3

I installed jre 1.8 and used [jarfix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html) to set environment variables.After that I installed netbeans IDE 7.3. When I run the netbeans the projects tries to starting modules (in blue centered window before starting netbeans). But suddenly this window disappears and IDE will not be opened.

After that i removed jdk 8 (and jre 1.8) and installed jre 1.7 instead. Now it works fine. But how I can configured netbeans so I can use jre 1.8 for my projects?

Comment: It is a bug in NetBeans, check my previous [answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944588/bug-can-not-start-netbeans-7-3-with-jdk-8

Comment: If you want to use java 1.8 you would benefit from using Netbeans 8 instead of 7.

Comment: dear @assylias can you paste your answers because it works for me.

Comment: dear @Vishrant I get copy of netbeans 8 and it works fine now! Thanks for your helps.